# Capture error message and execution details when executing stored proc in Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using a merge insert stored proc in Big query for CDC into Vault table from landing table . I am using airflow to copy the file in gcs and land into landing bigquery table. While executing stored proc I want to capture execution duration, start and finish, execution status details into workflow execution table for audit table. Any suggestion for the design and how I can get the error message in bigquery table on failure?

Thxs

Comment: What error do you recieve?

Comment: @ guillaume blaquiere  Haven't received any error . Which scripting variable in Bigquery can capture the error message while executing stored proc in Bigquery?

Comment: I don't understand! You haven't error and you would like to know the variable to capture error message. Do you have an example of what you want to achieve, even in pseudo code?

Comment: As per the above comments, I understand that you do not have any error. Could you please clarify what the issue is and share the code you have so far? As well as elaborate a little bit more on the process description.